# MailgunAPIError<Response [400]> with django-registration-redux

Tags: django

I'm trying to send registration emails by django-registration-redux, 
but got this response code: MailgunAPIError Response [400].

The code means 'Bad Request - Often missing a required parameter'
But i can send an email manually on my site, it's functional.

Am I missed some required parameter between registration-redux and mailgun?

This is my setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (...,
'registration' ,
)

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_mailgun.MailgunBackend'
MAILGUN_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxx'
MAILGUN_SERVER_NAME = 'xxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailgun.org'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='postmaster@xxxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'xxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

And this is my urls setting
path('accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself.

I changed the EMAIL_BACKEND  from 'django_mailgun.MailgunBackend' to 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' and it's OK.